# Phone number in SharePoint Profile not showing on users list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile

I've got an issue in my SharePoint 2013 Enterprise environment where a few users are showing blank phone numbers despite having a number listed in their SharePoint profile.

For example, if we look at John Doe in the Users List, he has no phone number listed. If we look at his actual profile in Central Administration, or on his My Site, the phone number is there. We are using SharePoint Profile Synchronization to get the information from AD, and I've tried forcing both a full and an incremental sync with no change. This issue isn't consistent, however, as most users have their phone numbers listed.

**How can we get the Users List for the site collection to consistently sync up with the user's SharePoint profile on the farm?**

Comment: Are you refering to the (hidden) User Information List? In what way are you using this list that missing the field is an issue for you?

Comment: What happens if you open up a profile in CA and save it? Does it replicate to the User Info List?

Comment: @RobertWagenaar - the User List may be hidden, but it determines what info shows up for a user added to a People Picker field. The initial issue was that certain users weren't showing phone numbers when assigned to tasks, projects, etc., so when troubleshooting that I checked the "All People" page for the site collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information like ULS and FIM Sync log entries it's hard to nail down an exact cause of the issue, and thus a resolution.

I've had issues with synchronization between UPS and UIL before as well, and running the following from the SP management shell as admin fixed for me:

> Stsadm.exe –o sync –listolddatabases 0
>
> Stsadm.exe –o sync –deleteolddatabases 0

This should provide a complete reset of the UIL on all sites and force a full sync. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Source: http://www.sharepointknight.com/2013/04/site-collection-users-list-out-of-sync-with-the-user-profile-store/

Comment: Answer accepted! This is essentially what I did last night (albeit in a roundabout manner) and now everything is showing up correctly.